# Angular scope doesn't update when removing an item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a simple application where I can add users to a list and remove them.

The form to add a new user binds to `$scope.newPerson`. On submitting the form, I add the `newPerson` object to `$scope.people` which is an array containing `person` objects.

I loop over the `people` array with an `ng-repeat` directive, to print out the people who are currently added to the scope. These rows all have a remove button (Jade snippet):

```
div.row(data-person, ng-repeat="person in people", ng-model="person")
    button(ng-click="removePerson(person)") Remove
```

When I click the Remove button, I execute this function:

```
$scope.removePerson = function(person) {
  var index = $scope.people.indexOf(person);
  if (index > -1) {
    $scope.people.splice(index, 1);
    person = null;
  }
}
```

This removes the row from the table, and sets the `person` scope to `null`. Batarang shows `{ This scope has no models }` afterwards.

However, I have noticed that my `people` array doesn't update. When I check it's scope in Batarang, the person I just deleted is still in that array. When I start typing to add a new person, it updates. If I submit the whole page to my server without doing this, the array still contains the removed people.

If i put `$scope.$apply()` after `person = null;`, I get the expected behaviour, however it throws an error that an `apply is in progress`. I also read calling `$apply()` yourself is considered bad practice. (?)

I'm new to Angular and I can't seem to find a lot of information about solving this problem. How would I make it update my array when I remove a person? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a quick jsfiddle or plnkr that demostrates your problem? I believe it's a scope issue, but there is not enough information in what you provided to see how all your scopes/directives/controllers are setup.

Comment: BTW, the person = null isn't doing anything other than setting person to null within the function (it does not change the person outside the function). Also, you are correct, you should never call apply yourself (other than in a directive in response to an external event).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did the following to fix this:

No more `ng-model` on the `ng-repeat` block:

```
div.row(data-person, ng-repeat="person in people")
```

Refactored the `ng-click` event for `removePerson()`:

```
<button ng-click="removePerson($index)">
    Remove
</button>
```

and changed the `removePerson()` code to this:

```
$scope.removePerson = function(index) {
  $scope.people.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Not sure if this actually fixed anything compared to my previous code, because I noticed that this was also a Batarang issue. When I simply log `{{ people }}` to my HTML, or `console.log($scope.people)`, I see the `people` array update. However, in Batarang, the array does not update.

Lesson learned: sometimes, logging stuff out yourself is better than relying on tools ;)

Answer (score -3):

slice method do not update your array, but return New one

Comment: Fairly sure I need `splice` here, not `slice`?